# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-multidex, dexguard

In our recent release of out application we are getting `Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt` more often, The stack-trace says that it didn`t find the class at **DexPathList**. We were using multidex previously but recently we have added dex-guard in out application and as per dex-guard documentation Multidex is handled by dex-guard. But here the crash is reported and it looks like dex-guard is not handling it properly. Here is complete stacktracke. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt.handleCoroutineExceptionImpl(:27)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerKt.handleCoroutineException(:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.handleFatalException(:146)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(:115)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
       
       
       Caused by java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler: Provider kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler not found
       at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:233)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:183)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:373)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(:786)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(:816)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(:807)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt.<clinit>(:23)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt.handleCoroutineExceptionImpl(:27)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerKt.handleCoroutineException(:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine.handleJobException(:192)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.finalizeFinishingState(:229)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath(:906)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(:863)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCompletingOnce$kotlinx_coroutines_core(:828)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(:100)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(:46)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(:106)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
       
       Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:371)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(:786)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(:816)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(:807)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt.<clinit>(:23)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt.handleCoroutineExceptionImpl(:27)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerKt.handleCoroutineException(:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine.handleJobException(:192)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.finalizeFinishingState(:229)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath(:906)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(:863)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCompletingOnce$kotlinx_coroutines_core(:828)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(:100)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(:46)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(:106)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
       
       Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.app.appname-dTd-4drfd8YfK38C73N7WQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.app.appname-dTd-4drfd8YfK38C73N7WQ==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.app.appname-dTd-4drfd8YfK38C73N7WQ==/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.appname-dTd-4drfd8YfK38C73N7WQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.app.appname-dTd-4drfd8YfK38C73N7WQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.app.appname-dTd-4drfd8YfK38C73N7WQ==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.app.appname-dTd-4drfd8YfK38C73N7WQ==/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /product/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:371)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416)
       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(:786)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(:816)
       at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(:807)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt.<clinit>(:23)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt.handleCoroutineExceptionImpl(:27)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerKt.handleCoroutineException(:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.StandaloneCoroutine.handleJobException(:192)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.finalizeFinishingState(:229)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath(:906)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(:863)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCompletingOnce$kotlinx_coroutines_core(:828)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(:100)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(:46)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(:106)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: did you fix this error?

Comment: not exactly, but we did a couple of things in our last release and occurrence is reduced to its minimum. 
1-Updated dex-guard,
2-updated co-routine dependencies, 
3-Add some dex-guard configurations from documentation

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the answer by Jake Wharton will help. We need to add these in proguard.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/214#issuecomment-362264056

More explained proguard data by vlc:

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/-/blob/master/application/app/proguard-rules.pro#L79-87